# Concurrent users and variables

Tags: google-app-maker

Need: for multiple users to use the app at the same time, being tracked by their own request id.

I've been using datasouce parameters to hold my "current place" variable, but I'm now uncertain whether that parameter is specific to this instance or if each user is going to overwrite it.

It looks like the apps script script properties is definitely shared between users. And I thought User Properties were being deprecated for apps script anyway.

How do you ensure concurrent use of your apps don't step on each others toes?

By script properties I mean these kinds of things:

```
function setProp(property, value) {

var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

scriptProperties.setProperty(property, value);

}

function getProp(property) {

var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

var value = scriptProperties.getProperty(property);

return value;

}
```

whereas when I'm using datasource properties I mean:

```
 var runID = app.datasources.requests.properties.current;
```

Comment: Datasource properties function much in the same way as query filters, i.e. they are unique to each session and therefore each user. Therefore it is more dependent on how you assign this property that points to each user's 'current place'. If it is based on a record from another model for example and each time a query is run against that model and it points to the last created record, then of course this would not work because it would point to the same record for all users.

Comment: good! I won't worry about it then

Comment: and I will make sure I never use last created record

Comment: You might be surprised actually. I just recently added a model to my application that required pulling the last record in a model and then incrementing the number value from one of the fields because another field is made up of a current fiscal year along with a self incrementing number. Of course in my onBeforeCreate function I also implement a record read lock so that concurrent users don't overwrite each other.